# Run Multiple Shell Scripts From One Shell Script

Tags: shell, ubuntu, terminal

Heres what I'm trying to do. I have 4 shell scripts. Script 1 needs to be run first, then 2, then 3, then 4, and they must be run in that order. Script 1 needs to be running (and waiting in the background) for 2 to function properly, however 1 takes about 3 seconds to get ready for use. I tried doing ./1.sh & ./2.sh & ./3.sh & ./4.sh, but this results in a total mess,since 2 starts requesting things from 1 when 1 is not ready yet. So, my question is, from one shell script, how do I get it to start script 1, wait like 5 seconds, start script 2, wait like 5 seconds, etc. without stopping any previous scripts from running (i.e. they all have to be running in the background for any higher numbered script to work). Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

May I introduce you to the `sleep` command?

```
./1.sh & sleep 5
./2.sh & sleep 5
./3.sh & sleep 5
./4.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
./1.sh &; sleep 5;./2.sh &; sleep 5; ./3.sh &; sleep 5; ./4.sh
```

Comment: You can use EITHER `&` OR `;` to terminate a command (with different implications); using BOTH will result in a syntax error.